# Android style changes not working with Samsung devices

Tags: java, android, android-styles, samsung-mobile, datepickerdialog

I want to change *DatePickerDialogs* and *TimePickerDialogs* globally using their spinner style. For that case I added *android:datePickerStyle* and *android:timePickerStyle* to my AppTheme. When I was testing the style changes, everything is fine on a virtual emulated Nexus device. But when I test it on an Samsung device, there where noch changed styles loaded. Both devices run with Nougat.

Here is a snippet from my style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/AppTheme.DatePicker</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/AppTheme.TimePicker</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DatePicker" parent="android:Widget.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:spinnersShown">true</item>
    <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TimePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

And that is the way I call the DatePickerDialog. (The TimePickerDialogs are called the same way)

```
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    getView().getContext(), SettingsFragment.this, 2000 , 10, 1);
 datePickerDialog.show();
```

*Settings.Fragment* is the fragment that calls the dialogs.

This it how it should look
[Nexus device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zsgl.png)

This it how it should not look
[Samsung device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70I9i.png)

Edit:
The Nexus device is a virtual emulated Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.1 and the Samsung device is a Samsung S7 Edge wit Android 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the problem myself.
The workaround is not to use the global styles. Instead I had to write my own DatePickerDialog.

In the custom dialog layout I could use the DatePicker preferences I wanted. This looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/spinnerDatePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:spinnersShown="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The custom dialog looks like the following:

```
public class SpinnerDatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private ISpinnerDatePickerDialogListener listener;
    private DatePicker datePicker;

    // this is no clean android fragment constructor, but we want to use it here
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public SpinnerDatePickerDialog(ISpinnerDatePickerDialogListener listener) {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Build the dialog and set up the button click handlers
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDatePicker);
        datePicker.updateDate(defaultYear, defaultMonth, defaultDay);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                    listener.onSpinnerDateDialogPositiveClick(SpinnerDatePickerDialog.this);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.abort, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Send the negative button event back to the host activity
                    listener.onSpinnerDateDialogNegativeClick(SpinnerDatePickerDialog.this);
                }
            });
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

To send values to the original fragment, I created an interface. The original fragment implements this interface and the custom dialog gets the fragment as an parameter in his constructor. This way I can trigger the listener in the original fragment.
The interface:

```
public interface ISpinnerDatePickerDialogListener {
    void onSpinnerDateDialogPositiveClick(SpinnerDatePickerDialog dialog);
    void onSpinnerDateDialogNegativeClick(SpinnerDatePickerDialog dialog);
}
```

The fragment class that calls the dialog:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements ISpinnerDatePickerDialogListener, ISpinnerTimePickerDialogListener {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // initialize listeners for text inputs, to open picker dialogs
        periodBegin = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editPeriodBegin);
        periodBegin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               showDialog(PERIOD_BEGIN_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * opens dialog for id
     *
     * @param id
     */
    private void showDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
            case PERIOD_BEGIN_DIALOG_ID:
                SpinnerDatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
                datePickerDialog = new SpinnerDatePickerDialog(this);
                datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), datePickerDialog.getTAG());
                break;

    }

    @Override
    public void onSpinnerDateDialogPositiveClick(SpinnerDatePickerDialog dialog) {
        // TODO send DatePicker values with listener
        // load DatePicker from dialog and set them to EditText text
        DatePicker datePicker = dialog.getDatePicker();
        int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = datePicker.getMonth();
        int year = datePicker.getYear();

        // TODO
        String formattedDate = FORMAT.format(new Date(year - 1900, month, day));
        periodBegin.setText(formattedDate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpinnerDateDialogNegativeClick(SpinnerDatePickerDialog dialog) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use the AlertDialog builder context to inflate the custom views: LayoutInflater.from(builder.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null); If you use AppCompat, the AlertDialog theme is an overlay theme applied over the Activity theme.

Comment: Thank you so much. Have had so much pain with Samsung overriding the default themes for so long... This works!

Comment: Fragments should always have no-arg contructor. There is another solution that will allow you to use a callback listener inside of the fragment. Utilize the method getActivity or getParentFragment().